# New Multilevel list in Microsoft Word without putting headings in Navigation Pane

Tags: microsoft-word, navigation, outline

I'm looking to make a multilevel list style in Microsoft Word that has two levels as I've shown below:

Q01. Number level for the question?
   a) Multiple choice answers

I want the questions in the first level to show up in my navigation pane as Level 2 headings so that I can navigate to questions quickly. However, I do not want to see the answers in the navigation pane.

How can I do this easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your new style for Q01 numbering, Format | Paragraph and change Outline Level (on the Indents and Spacing tab) to Level 1 (from default of Body Text).